# Docdokuplm not running after docker deployment

Tags: java, configuration, payara

I am not able to see the main page once docker compose has completed the deployment, I am following the steps shown in this guide. https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm-docker

Instead of the front page at http://localhost:8080, I receive the message "Server isn't available, please try again"

this is the output for the ./start.sh

```bash
arield@vm-nebula:~/Projects/docdokuplm/docdoku-plm-docker$ ./start.sh 
Data directory found
/home/arield/Projects/docdokuplm/docdoku-plm-docker/data
Keystore found
/home/arield/Projects/docdokuplm/docdoku-plm-docker/keystore
Pulling front      ... done
Pulling es         ... done
Pulling kibana     ... done
Pulling db         ... done
Pulling smtp       ... done
Pulling back       ... done
Pulling adminer    ... done
Pulling zookeeper  ... done
Pulling kafka      ... done
Pulling conversion ... done
Pulling ssl-proxy  ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_front_1     ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_zookeeper_1 ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_smtp_1      ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_db_1        ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_es_1        ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_kafka_1     ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_adminer_1   ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_kibana_1    ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_back_1      ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_conversion_1 ... done
Recreating docdoku-plm-docker_ssl-proxy_1  ... done
```

Everything seems ok...

Do I need a server in addition to the docker deployment?